# flask sqlitedb connection error Working outside of application context

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

```
>>> from app import db
>>> db.create_all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\kinut\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 868, in create_all
    self._call_for_binds(bind_key, "create_all")
  File "C:\Users\kinut\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 839, in _call_for_binds
    engine = self.engines[key]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kinut\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 628, in engines
    app = current_app._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kinut\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
    raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

i ran into this error while trying to create an sqlite database

expected no return, just creation of the database

Answer (score 0):

```
from mycode import app
from mycode import db
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```